# Automatic Motion Detection in existing GoPro video files

Tags: video

I have quite some hours of footage stored on disc. It's all static video of a bird's nest.

Is anybody aware of an application that makes it easy to automatically scan these files and to jump ahead to the next sequence in which motion is detected?

Thank you very much, 
J.

Answer (score 2):

[iSpy Connect](http://www.ispyconnect.com/) may be able to help you here. I've haven't played about it with it much but I know you can load an existing video file into it and it will detect motion.